# multiple logical operators in shell script causing an issue

Tags: shell

I am trying to write an expression using multiple logical operators and shell script as below

```
if [ [a != b] && [ -d "/path/to/directory"] || [a = b] && [ ! -d "/path/to/directory"] ] ; then execute some steps.
```

When I run this code, I get syntax error in conditional operator ']'. I tried different ways of having brackers, but could not get it to work. Can someone please help. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could seperate the condition expression and keep the value in variant, like this to avoid the unpaired parenthesis problem:

```
CON_1=((a != b) && [ -d "/path/to/directory"])
CON_2=((a == b) && [ ! -d "/path/to/directory"])
if CON_1 || CON_2
then
  # execute some steps
fi
```

*Or* try using eclipse plugin **ShellEd** for the alternative way.

**EDIT** Change the syntax to be shell. I assumed [] in this context is the logical test operation. Any one please suggest whether it is correct.

Comment: I have just copied the `[ -d "/path/to/directory"]` to insert to the variable but I do not know neither what does it mean nor it is right syntax.

Comment: Uh - judging from the use of forward-slashes in paths, I'm assuming this is a Unix shell question.  But your answer looks like it is for some Windows shell

Comment: Ah, I am sorry for my mistake.. but I still suggest to separate the expression idea.